# nextSequenceToken in case of exception after putLogEvents

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I am looping thru some data, uploading elements to CloudWatch. The essence of the loop is these 2 lines:

```
const response = await this.cloudwatch.putLogEvents(params).promise();
seqToken = response.nextSequenceToken;
```

Basically - upload data to the CloudWatch and get next sequence token for consecutive upload. This works fine as long as there are no exceptions. If exception happens (e.g. upload size is too large) I'd like to put it into `try/catch` block, log the error message and continue with the loop.

My question is: in lieu of valid response how do I get valid `nextSequenceToken` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, you can simply reuse the token that you already have.

The only exception (pun not intended) is if you get `InvalidSequenceTokenException`. In that case, you need to get a new sequence token. You can either call `DescribeLogStreams`, or (per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html#API_PutLogEvents_Errors) -- I've never done this) get `expectedSequenceToken` from the exception object.

As a general comment, you should review the list of operation-specific exceptions (link above), as well as the [list of common errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html). Some exceptions are retryable, some are not, and you need to handle them appropriately.